# SyntaxError: missing ; before statement print "result";

Tags: php, printing

I'm new in PHP. I got error on this code so please anyone help me out.

```
<p> <script> print "result";</script>
```

Comment: Post your tried code...

Comment: we are not getting what exactly you want to say...give more code so that we can help you...

Answer (score 1):

See [Escaping from HTML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php)

If you want to use the script element syntax then you need HTML 3.2 style `<script language="php">`. Without the language attribute, PHP will pass it through unmodified and then the browser will process it as JavaScript.

Don't use the script element syntax though, nobody does. Use:

```
<p><?php print "result"; ?>
```